# How do I generate a linq to xml infoset w/ a DTD reference?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I need to generate an xml infoset but the infoset needs to contain a reference to a client's DTD. The desired out needs to contain this DTD reference

```
<!DOCTYPE AutoApplication SYSTEM "http://www.clientsite.com/public/DTD/autoappV1-3-level2.dtd">
```

This reference sits directly benath the xml declaration. Neither XProcessingInstruction or XDeclaration do the job, is there another type I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add your dtd using a XDocumentType object. see [here](http://csharpfeeds.com/post/8274/LINQ_To_XML_Im_hooked.aspx) for more info.  It should be noted that xlinq has pretty limited processing for DTD's, though ([see msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocumenttype.aspx)).

[some sample code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/XML-LINQ/CreatingaDocumentTypeandAddingIttoaDocument.htm)....

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
public class MainClass 
{
   public static void Main() 
   {
      XDocument xDocument = new XDocument();
      XDocumentType documentType = new XDocumentType("Books", null, "Books.dtd", null);
      xDocument.Add(documentType, new XElement("Books"));
      Console.WriteLine(xDocument);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this xml fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE AutoApplication SYSTEM "http://www.clientsite.com/public/DTD/autoappV1-3-level2.dtd">
```

We would do:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XDocumentType("AutoApplication", null, "http://www.clientsite.com/public/DTD/autoappV1-3-level2.dtd", null));
);
```